# Avoiding: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows errors in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm newbie in plsql.

I'm getting error

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

The problem is that from time to time I need to select from cursor that have duplicate rows
To avoid this situation I tried to add
rownum=1 or rownum<2

But this didn't solve the issue

```
select work into my_work  
from INFO 
where person_id = in_person_id
and date= (select max(date) from INFO where (person_id = in_person_id and rownum<2     
));
```

P.S. the original bug produce duplicate rows cannot be fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rownum <2` applied to subquery, not to the main one. It should be

```
select work into my_work  
from INFO 
where person_id = in_person_id
and date= (select max(date) from INFO where (person_id = in_person_id 
--and rownum<2  
)) 
AND rownum<2  ;
```

Comment: Thanks , nice and fast answer !